# Keep the cell in editing mode even after scrolling down to other data rows and coming back by scrolling up

Tags: ag-grid

I have set cellEditor for a particular column in grid. When user clicks on that cell, a cell turns to editable mode where user can enter text. But without focusing out if he scrolls down to see other rows of grid and again comes back to the row where he partially entered text before scrolling down, The text has been cleared and has left editing mode to view mode. how can I fix it so that it stays in editing mode and the data is also retained. I am using ag-grid-enterprise v5.0.7

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update to the latest version, It doesn't seem to have this issue. Or try using the `cellEditor: 'popupText'`, as a final resort, turn off row virtualization by setting `rowBuffer: 999999` or some large number.

Here is more detail about the bug that was reported:

https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1424

Comment: can we freely upgrade to latest version? we purchased the license when the ag-grid was in version v5.0.7

Comment: It says on their pricing page that liscenses are perpetual, meaning you get updates for a year or so... However you should check their [support page](https://www.ag-grid.com/support.php) for more information, especially since they have more dedicated support forums for enterprise users